# how to updata all changes on database as one block

Tags: django, django-models

I have this code

```py
for i in range(100):
    table2.objects.create(id = i, some_extra_fields)
```

how to upload all database changes one time in one query

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bulk_create` to create multiple objects at once:

```py
new_records = []

for i in range(100):
    new_records.append(Table(id=i, ...))


Table.objects.bulk_create(new_records)
```

Docs in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the tables you want to use, for example with list comprehension:

```
table2.objects.bulk_create(
    [table2(id=i, a=some_extra_fields) for i in range(100)]
)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`table2`</s> to `Table2`.